# Why are all my NSManagedObjects being faulted immediately?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm running a very basic fetch request that returns about 2000 objects. I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController with a batchSize of 15.

```
    predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.tagName==%@", currentTagObject.tagName];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createDate" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:15];
   self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"createDay" cacheName:nil];
```

The fetch request takes over 10 seconds though. I've enabled SQLite debugging so I can see what's going on. I think it's fetching all 2000 entities, with only 15 with actual values, then for some reason going through each and every of the 2000 objects and faulting them in.

During the fetch, these lines appear thousands of times:

```
2012-06-22 21:14:47.546 app[9227:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0107s
2012-06-22 21:14:47.551 app[9227:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0171s for 15 rows.
2012-06-22 21:14:47.568 app[9227:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZAUTHOREMAIL, t0.ZAUTHORNAME, t0.ZCREATEDATE, t0.ZISGLOBAL, t0.ZISLOCKED, t0.ZISNEW, t0.ZISPENDINGDELETE, t0.ZISPENDINGSYNC, t0.ZLASTUPDATED, t0.ZLOCALLYMODIFIEDDATE, t0.ZMETALASTUPDATED, t0.ZNOTEID, t0.ZNUMBEROFCHILDREN, t0.ZPARENTAUTHOREMAIL, t0.ZPARENTNOTEID, t0.ZROOTAUTHOREMAIL, t0.ZROOTNOTEID, t0.Z4PENDINGADDNOTES, t0.Z4PENDINGREMOVENOTES FROM ZMBNOTEOBJECT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZCREATEDATE DESC LIMIT 15
...thousands more lines exactly similar to the three above
```

My table only shows 5 cells a time, so I have no idea why all the objects are being faulted in immediately. What could be causing this? Why would all the objects be faulted in immediately without me even scrolling my table? Can it be that they are being accessed somewhere, perhaps iterated? Does calling `NSArray *fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`cause all objects to be faulted by any chance?

Comment: What happens when you take out the sort descriptor?

Comment: An NSFetchedResultsController fetch needs a sort descriptor. I get a crash if I try to take it out

Comment: I wonder if it's a memory thing.  By looking at the select statement it appears this object graph has children and is a little more complex than just a simple value object.  Have you tried setting includesSubentities to NO and running it?

Comment: Show us your entity and the relationship with the tags. Also you have batch size of 15, so it's normal all other 1985 items to be faulted - they will be lazy loaded when needed. Also why do you use a `compare:` method for the sort descriptor?

Comment: But why would they be faulted right away without me even accessing them? Is that normal? And I'm not even sure if they're being faulted. I just assumed that the three lines above (repeating thousands of times) were the objects being faulted. What do those 3 log lines represent anyway? What do they mean? I'm using compare: to sort the results by their NSDate property createDate.

Comment: And even if I don't set a predicate at all (that is, fetch all entities), I still get the same results (as in, weird log statements and a 10+ second fetch request)

Comment: And commenting out the batchSize line does not cause thousands of output lines for some reason..

Comment: Try with `NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createDate" ascending:NO];` and see if the request takes shorter..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out what it says in the documentation about `batchSize` (my emphasis):

> The default value is 0. A batch size of 0 is treated as infinite, which disables the batch faulting behavior.
>
> If you set a non-zero batch size, the collection of objects returned when the fetch is executed is broken into batches. When the fetch is executed, **the entire request is evaluated** and the identities of all matching objects recorded, but **no more than `batchSize` objects’ data will be fetched** from the persistent store **at a time**. The array returned from executing the request will be a proxy object that transparently faults batches on demand. (In database terms, this is an in-memory cursor.)
>
> You can use this feature to restrict the working set of data in your application. In combination with fetchLimit, you can create a subrange of an arbitrary result set.

So, clearly, according to this explanation, you get 2000/15 round trips to the store. That will certainly take some time. You need all the data because of your sort and the `ANY`predicate but you instructed the request to only get 15 at a time.

Also, for completeness, from the previous comments: drop the `compare` from your sort descriptor.

Comment: I get that point, but the question no one is answering is that, although it takes 2000/15 roundtrips, it shouldn't do all these round trips immediately when executing the request should it? It should execute each round trip when the data is accessed. Currently all of these round trips are occurring in the initial fetch, making the request take 10+ seconds for 2000 results. This cannot be typical, can it?

Comment: I do not get your objection. The statement "It should not do all these round trips immediately when executing the request." is false. Think about it...

Comment: I figured out the reason this was happening. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170762/dynamic-uitableview-height-with-core-data-objects

Comment: As written in the comment, this is not true at all. `NSFetchedResultsController` does its fetches from the underlying persistent store directly, so it doesn't need to fault all the objects to sort/filter. The problem here was that something else was requesting for all the objects and then they were faulted at batchSize strides.
ps: I think that `estimatedRowHeight` is there mainly for that reason :)

Comment: Downvote. As rightly commented out by @DeFrenZ, sort and filters are done when the fetch is executed. They do not add as many round trips to store.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you see is well described in Core Data Programming Guide under [Batch-faulting and Pre-fetching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW6) paragraph.

In short, you should pre-fetch the tags objects if you are using a predicate to fetch objects that have a tag with a specific name. That is because normally when fetching your objects Core Data does not fetch related objects, but uses faults instead. Now your predicate triggers firing those faults individually which is slow.