# Does calling the fetchedObjects property of an NSFetchedResultsController fault all objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm trying to debug a [strange problem I'm having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166271/why-are-all-my-nsmanagedobjects-being-faulted-immediately), and I'm absolutely clueless where to begin. This question is simple though:

I have a fetch request that returns about 2000 objects, but with a batchSize of 15. So only 15 objects are loaded into memory, the rest are faulted in as they are needed. The issue I'm having is that for some reason all my objects are being faulted in immediately when the fetch request finishes. This takes about 20 seconds. I don't understand why it's happening.

It must mean I'm accessing all these objects somehow, causing them all to be faulted. Does calling `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count` cause all objects to be faulted by any chance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are all my NSManagedObjects being faulted immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166271/why-are-all-my-nsmanagedobjects-being-faulted-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents say this about `fetchedObjects`

> If the fetch request has no predicate, then the results array includes all instances of the entity specified by the fetch request.

What are you trying to do?  The correct way to get the count is like this:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [controllers sections] objectAtIndex:section];

return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why my objects are all being faulted even though I'm not accessing them..over 2000 objects are being faulted even though my table only displays 4 cells a time

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166271/why-are-all-my-nsmanagedobjects-being-faulted-immediately

Comment: Did you stop using fetchedObjects yet?  You don't ever need to use it for just displaying in a table view.

Comment: Ya but didn't make a difference

Comment: In that case, no one has any information to go on.  You need to post info about your model and where you use it.