# Core Data Consuming Lots of Memory when used with Dynamic Tableview Height For Row

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a problem with core data consuming a lot of memory on my iphone. On start i set up a fetchrequest as follows:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweets" inManagedObjectContext: [[ChubbyEyetwitterEngine sharedInstance] getManagedObjectContextForUse]]; 

NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isWatchList==NO && favorited == NO  && accountHolder.id_str == %@ ",[[ChubbyEyetwitterEngine sharedInstance] getActiveUserID]];

// Define how we will sort the records
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[sortTweetaryTimeLine objectForKey:@"sortKey"] ascending:[[sortTweetaryTimeLine objectForKey:@"ascending"] boolValue]] autorelease];   

NSSortDescriptor *secondarySortKey = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:FALSE] autorelease]; 


NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            sortDescriptor,
                            secondarySortKey,nil];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
{
    //smaller batch on iphone
    [request setFetchBatchSize:12];

}else {
    //bigger on the ipad
    [request setFetchBatchSize:100];

}

//prefetching important relationships to cache data
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ownerOfThisTweetary",@"thisEntity", nil]];


diaryFetchResultsController= [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[[ChubbyEyetwitterEngine sharedInstance] getManagedObjectContextForUse] sectionNameKeyPath:[sortTweetaryTimeLine objectForKey:@"sectionName"] cacheName:nil] ;   




NSError *fetchError = nil;
if ([diaryFetchResultsController performFetch:&fetchError]) {

}else
{

}

diaryFetchResultsController.delegate = self;
```

After this i call reloadData on my tabeview.  In my tableview i dynamically calculate my height for the cells based on the length of the text property as well as other properties on my managedobject and return the height.

The problem here is that on calling reload data, all the objects in the fetchedresultscontroller have heightforrow called, this in turn faults the objects into memory. Now my tableview has a lot of objects, going into the hundreds, and my memory consumption balloons up.

Im looking for a way to save up on memory :

What ive tried To Do:
    [diaryFetchResultsController.managedObjectContext setStalenessInterval:2.0]; 
this didnt have any effect, or at least an effect that i could see so i tried something else->

inside the heightForRowAtIndexPath, after i calculate the height, i tried         [diaryFetchResultsController.managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:YES];
the result was bad, and resulted in an infinite loop, what was actually happening is that  when the object is faulted, the system automatically calls  heightForRowAtIndexPath for that indexpath.

My second try was removing refresh object out of the heightForRowAtIndexPath and instead insert at the end of my cellForRowAtIndexPath. Same result as above.

My third try::

-(void) turnMeBackIntoAfault{

```
  for (id object in diaryFetchResultsController.fetchedObjects){

    [diaryFetchResultsController.managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:YES];
 }
```

}

i then call this method immediately after calling reloadData on the tableview. The result was that the heightForRowAtIndexPath was called once for all the cells(as expected), then turnMeBackIntoAfault is called on all manageobjects. However, the bad news is that immediately after The the system calls heightForRowAtIndexPath for all the cells once again, hence negating the effects of turning objects back into faults.
I also tried setting tableveiw delegates & datasources to nil & fetchedresultscontroller delegates to nil before the faulting and setting them back to self again after loop but the effects are still the same.

Now im absolutely sure that its the heightForRowAtIndexPath thats causing the large memory consumption. Ive experimented with heightForRowAtIndexPath commented out, and i have almost over 1.5x as much memory free available.

Having dynamic rows is essential to my app, and im running into low memory conditions as my application makes extensive use of fetchedresultControllers and tableviews.

Any help saving memory would be greatly appreciated! Ive been scratching my head all day on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic UITableView height with Core Data objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170762/dynamic-uitableview-height-with-core-data-objects)

Comment: That question and some of the related ones should have some help for you. Basically your batch size is irrelevant, the table view needs a height for every row in the table, and if it has to fully load a managed object to do that, that's what it does.